# Передать файл (изображение) в переменную через POST в Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit

Здравствуйте. Как передать файл(jpeg, png, jpg) в переменную через POST в Retrofit 2 ?
Есть такой запрос:
[image: запрос в POSTMAN]
Запрос со скриншота выше нормально отрабатывает в Postman. 
В приложении есть возможность вместе с другими данными отправить и файл. Если не отправляю файл, то использую такой код:

`@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("create_user")
Call<String> addUser(@Query("token") String token, @FieldMap Map<String, Object> params);`

```
 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("user_id", какое-то_значение);
 params.put("login", какое-то_значение);
 params.put("password", какое-то_значение);
 ApiController.addUser(getToken(getActivity()), params);
```

Этот код отрабатывает нормально. То есть, если пользователь не отправляет файл, то все работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно доделать, чтобы была возможность отправить файл. Раньше переделывал изображение в base64 и как строку вставляли её в одно из полей в запросе. Но теперь нужно сделать запрос именно так как на скриншоте в Postman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылку от пользователя pavel163 я видел раньше. Но ночью не заметил переключение пунктов. Ответ оказался в подпункте [Passing Multiple Parts Along a File with @PartMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-passing-multiple-parts-along-a-file-with-partmap). В статье советовали использовать [FileUtils](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java), но обошёлся без него. Ниже привожу используемый мной код.

Методы из вопроса были заменены на следующие:

```
    @Multipart
    @POST("create_user")
    Call<String> addUser(@Query("token") String token, @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody> partMap, @Part MultipartBody.Part file);

    File file = new File(mFilePath);
    MultipartBody.Part body = ApiUtils.prepareFilePart(getActivity(), "image", file);
    RequestBody login = createPartFromString(mEdtLogin.getText().toString());
    RequestBody password = createPartFromString(mEdtPassword.getText().toString());
    RequestBody userId = createPartFromString(mUserId + "");

    HashMap<String, RequestBody> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("login", login);
    params.put("password", password);
    params.put("user_id", userId);
    ApiController.addUser(PreferencesUtils.getToken(getActivity()), params, body);
```

Допольно использовались методs createPartFromString() и prepareFilePart(). Ниже код:

```
 private RequestBody createPartFromString(String descriptionString) {
    return RequestBody.create(
            okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);
}

@NonNull
public static MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(Context context, String partName, File file) {

    String mimeType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(file.getName());
    RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(mimeType),file);

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
}
```

Comment: в строчке `    MultipartBody.Part body = ApiUtils.prepareFilePart(getActivity(), "image", file);
` что означает `"image"`?

Comment: @zayn1991 "image" - название переменной в которую я передаю изображение. Выше в моем вопросе есть скриншот, там это видно. Вместо "image" будет другое название, которое требует от вас апи, с которым вы работаете. К примеру, в реальном проекте я должен был обновлять пользователю аватар и по требованию апи эта переменная называлась "avatar" (эта стркоа была вместо "image").

Answer (score 0):

Вот в этой [статье](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server) пример кода на стороне андроида и на стороне сервера. Отправка любого файла на сервер.

```
public interface FileUploadService {  
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part file
    );
}


private void uploadFile(Uri fileUri) {  
    // create upload service client
    FileUploadService service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(FileUploadService.class);

    // https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java
    // use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(
                         MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(fileUri)),
                         file
             );

    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("picture", file.getName(), requestFile);

    // add another part within the multipart request
    String descriptionString = "hello, this is description speaking";
    RequestBody description =
            RequestBody.create(
                    okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM, descriptionString);

    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload(description, body);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.v("Upload", "success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Это не решение проблемы, у вас не ответ на вопрос. Это отписка "вот тебе удочка думай сам" -- ничем не лучше, чем отсылка "идите в гугл, там ищите". Статья на английском. В общем, как ни глянь -- ваша ремарка тянет на ответ. Надо её и сделать комментарием, либо переписать из текста по ссылке основные моменты.